# Python: Different results when executing a code in Eclipse and Pycharm

Tags: python, eclipse, encoding, character-encoding, pycharm

I have a problem (probably with encoding but I'm not sure). I have a program (couple of *.py files). I've written this program in Eclipse Juno. Now when I'm trying to execute it in cmd line or PyCharm, I'm getting different results.

This program takes one word as an argument and returns similar words

Here is the main function:

```
def getPhrase(self,pattern):

    matcher = automat.Matcher(self.englishArr)
    if len(pattern)>6:
        dist=int(len(pattern)/3)
        print("6")
    elif len(pattern)>3:
        dist=2
    else: return [] 

    results=list(automata.find_all(pattern, dist, matcher))
    return results
```

englishArr is an array which contains many english words

Results of this command: `print(getPhrase("doktor"))`:

Executed by Eclipse: `['debtor', 'doctor', 'doctors', 'dolor', 'donor', 'door', 'doter', 'motor', 'rotor']`

Executed by cmd Win7: `['debtor']`

Executed by PyCharm: `['debtor']`

I've attached automata.py in case it is necessary to see it's code: https://gist.github.com/Arachnid/491973

What could be the problem? Encoding? I've tried many encodings and it seems it doesn't work. Thanks

EDIT: I find out that I have set cp1250 as default project encoding in Eclipse so I tried to change it in PyCharm too, no changes...

Comment: Are you sure eclipse is using the same instance of python.  Check your paths and libraries.